# adobe air AS3 :How to run a function in workers_ Multithreading (by Workers)

Tags: multithreading, actionscript-3, flash, air, adobe

I have a heavy function that is not proper to be executed in the main timeline (because it takes a long time to be finished and crashes the program ) .
therefore I searched for multithreading in air(as3) but all the examples I found has explained how to run separate swf  files in workers .how can I run a function in a worker(thread)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Official worker documentation ( http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/Worker.html ): Each additional worker is created from a separate swf.

Thus, you are either to arrange your heavy code as an additional SWF or to refactor it so you can pause and resume it and spread its execution along multiple frames (ENTER_FRAME events, not timeline frames, ofc).

P.S. On the very same documentation page there's a way to run main SWF in two workers so you can fork it into controlling application and worker application.

```
 // The primordial worker's main class constructor
 public function PrimordialWorkerClass()
 {
   init();
 }

 private function init():void
 {
   var swfBytes:ByteArray = this.loaderInfo.bytes;

   // Check to see if this is the primordial worker
   if (Worker.current.isPrimordial)    
   {
     // create a background worker
     var bgWorker:Worker = WorkerDomain.current.createWorker(swfBytes);

     // listen for worker state changes to know when the worker is running
     bgWorker.addEventListener(Event.WORKER_STATE, workerStateHandler);

     // set up communication between workers using 
     // setSharedProperty(), createMessageChannel(), etc.
     // ... (not shown)

     bgWorker.start();
   }
   else // entry point for the background worker
   {
     // set up communication between workers using getSharedProperty()
     // ... (not shown)

     // start the background work
   }
 }
```

Comment: thanks dear Organis ,I'm a user from iran and adobe has blocked our ip ,can you please post an example for " run main SWF in two workers "

Comment: Done. You also might want to use some online anonymizer proxy which will solve that inconvenient blockage for you.

Comment: @AmirRasti if you use Chrome browser, try an extension for it called UltraSurf VPN. Also get AdBlock too. Then you can see any website in the world unblocked.